# RxJS, Typescript and the dreaded 'Type Mismatch' warning/error

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, rxjs, typescript-generics

I *know* I'm missing something obvious. Below is pseudo code that actually works in production. But, the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) is giving me an error that I can't crack. It can be suppressed with `noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes`, but, what I'd really like to know is what's going on:

```js
this.authService.onAuthStateChanged()
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
            this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
                map(params => params['returnUrl'])
            )
        )
    )
    .subscribe(([authState, returnUrl]) => {
        // [...]
    });
```

The error I get on the `subscribe` line:

> Argument type ([authState, returnUrl]: readonly [any, any]) => void is not assignable to parameter type Partial<Observer<[(AuthState | undefined), ...unknown[]]>> | undefined

Other pertinent details?

```js
// AuthState is just a POJO.
onAuthStateChanged(): BehaviorSubject<AuthState | undefined>

// This is Angular's params object.
// https://angular.io/api/router/Params
export declare type Params = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

I'm using `RxJS ~7.5.0`, and `Typescript ~4.7.4`. I'm also using `Angular ^14.2.0`, although this really isn't an Angular problem.

So, what is supposed to happen here? `onAuthStateChanged` emits `AuthState` or `undefined` depending on whether the user is logged in. This is combined with a query parameter called `returnUrl`, which is a `string`, of course.

Now, the way the syntax used to work is that the two observables would be available using a destructuring assignment signature `([authState, returnUrl])` -- at least I think that's what it's called. And as I said, it compiles and executes correctly in real life And as others have shown here, also  does not error on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ps1jho?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) (updated to more closely match my environment with identical `tslint`, `angular.json` etc.).

And yet, my beloved IntelliJ...

Could it be that I am looking at a breaking change in the latest version of RxJS:

> withLatestFrom
>
> - Generic signatures have changed. Do not explicitly pass generics.
>
> Source: https://rxjs.dev/6-to-7-change-summary#withlatestfrom

Which is grand, except that it still compiles and runs. So, two things:

1. What is happening behind the scenes to cause this error in IntelliJ?
2. How do I make it go away? I've tried strongly typing all the parameters, to no avail...

Comment: why do you call `onAuthStateChanged``as a method ? I Get [no error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xpx2mu?file=index.ts)

Comment: Good question. The `BehaviorSubject` is contained in a separate service, and being an old Java guy, I'm not a big fan of external consumers directly accessing class properties/members. For the sake of this question, it should be thought of just as an observable that emits.

Comment: @MichaelDeSoto https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdnt5o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I have created demo here. But I have not seen any type error.

Comment: I think I'm just seeing an IDE specific type hinting "issue." I updated my question with a StackBlitz example closer to my real application (https://angular-ivy-ps1jho.stackblitz.io/).  As others have said, I cannot reproduce the error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-57220](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57220/Invalid-type-mismatch-warning-for-observablesubscribe), please follow it for updates

Enabling the Typescript language service in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** should help to get rid of the error

Comment: Hooray! For filing the bug, yes. But really for ultimately leading me to the solution. While I had the "Typescript language service" turned on, it turns out that version selected did not match my project. Correcting this removed the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `onAuthStateChanged` as either a function that returns a `BehaviourSubject` or, directly, as a `BehaviourSubject`, you should not have any error.

The following code does not produce any type error

```
type AuthState = {};

let onAuthStateChanged = new BehaviorSubject<AuthState | undefined>(null);
let onAuthStateChangedFunc: () => BehaviorSubject<AuthState | undefined>;

// This is Angular's params object.
// https://angular.io/api/router/Params
type Params = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

class Foo {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  foo() {
    onAuthStateChangedFunc() // or
    // onAuthStateChanged
      .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
          this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
            map((params) => params['returnUrl'])
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(([authState, returnUrl]) => {
        // [...]
      });
  }
}
```

The variables `[authState, returnUrl]` are correctly identified of type `AuthState` and `any` respectively.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6yzwfb?file=index.ts) for reference

Comment: I think I'm just seeing an IDE specific type hinting "issue." I updated my question with a StackBlitz example closer to my real application (https://angular-ivy-ps1jho.stackblitz.io/).  As others have said, I cannot reproduce the error either.